# What is a cycle hypergraph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, algebraic-graph-theory, hypergraphs

What is a cycle hypergraph? Could someone give me good reference or illustrate with a few examples?

Comment: How do you define hypergraph? How do you define a cycle in one of them?

Comment: It's been my experience that hypergraph terminology isn't very standardized, so I would check with individual references.

Answer (score 3):

This can be one visual alternative. Concepts of hypergraphs won’t be addressed in this answer. In any case, the paper **“Directed hypergraph and applications”** of Giorgio Gallo, Giustino Longo, Sang Nguyen,and Stefano Pallottino is a good support.

In order to explain the concept, i'll use a form of graph coloring applied to hypergraphs.

**Contact Coloring and Hypergraphs**

Every pair hyperedge-vertex will be called contact.

[image]

The action of coloring contacts in a hypergraph will be called “Contact Coloring of a Hypergraph”.

[image]

The contacts of a hypergraph are divided in two groups, the contacts whose vertices are in the tail of a hyperedge will be called tail contacts, and those whose vertices are in the head, will be called head contacts.

Moving through a hyperedge of a directed hypergraph is moving from a vertex that belongs to the tail of the hyperedge to a vertex that belongs to the head of the hyperedge, then it is said that the hyperedge was passed.

[image]

The action of assign a same color to all the head contacts that belongs to a directed hypergraph will be called “Contact Coloring of directed Hypergraphs”.

[image]

Also is possible to assign colors to the head contacts of a path of a certain hypergraph, that will be called “coloring the head contacts that belong to a path of a certain hypergraph”, o shortly, “coloring contact of a directed path”, at the same time, an alternative way to represent a path of a certain directed path of a hypergraph.

**Properties of a Cycle Hypergraph of level N and length L**

- It has only hyperedges with N vertices, and only vertices of degree N.
- It has L number of vertices, and L number of hyperedges.
- It is possible to find at least a set of N directed paths, where:

  1. Every path has a length of L.
  2. Every hyperedges is a backward-hyperedge.
  3. It is possible pass through each hyperedge once (Eulerian path).
  4. It is possible pass through each vertex once (Hamiltonian path).
  5. If N = L, we going to call it trivial cycle hypergraph, on the contrary, it will be called non-trivial cycle hypergraph.

**Visualization of the features of a Cycle Hypergraph**

- In order to visualize the eulerian property of a cycle hypergraph, we are going to use the directed versions of the hypergraph.
- In order to visualize the hamiltonian property of a cycle hypergraph, we are going to use the versions of the hypergraph with directed contact coloring, all combined harmoniously in the same hypergraph.

**Trivial hypergraph of level 2**

[image]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CMj-Hf0WIAAZDJU.png))</sub>

**Trivial hypergraph of level 3**

[image]

**Non-trivial cycle hypergraph of level 2 and length of 5**

[image]

**Non-trivial cycle hypergraph of level 3 and length of 27**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: By the way, one thing is "cycle hypergraph" and the other is "cycle in a hypergraph", slighty different, is like "cycle graph" vs "cycle in a graph".

Answer (score 2):

There could be more than one definition. One is $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}, E = \{(v_1,v_2,v_3),(v_3,v_4,v_5),(v_5,v_6,v_7),\dots(v_{n-1},v_n,v_1)\}$.

Another one is $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}, E = \{(v_1,v_2,v_3),(v_2,v_3,v_4),(v_3,v_4,v_5),\dots,(v_{n-1},v_n,v_1),(v_n,v_1,v_2)\}$.

Comment: Basically what you are saying is if $n$ is large, the number of such cycle hypergraphs is large. Is this correct? What is a good reference for these graphs?

Comment: @JAS I'm not sure about references. Maybe you can find something here http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gsarkozy/Cikkek/36.pdf

Comment: That seems way up there. Anything on foundational level?