# Does a path can be Hamiltonian and Eulerian at the same time?

Tags: graph-theory

If so does it force it to be a simple circle?

Or any other restrictions?

How would it look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this post can bring some light : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512581/what-is-a-cycle-hypergraph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A path is Hamiltonian if each vertex is visited exactly once.  A path is Eulerian if every edge is traversed exactly once.  Clearly, these conditions are not mutually exclusive for all graphs:  if a simple connected graph $G$ itself consists of a path (so exactly two vertices have degree $1$ and all other vertices have degree $2$), then that path is both Hamiltonian and Eulerian.  If $G$ is a cycle, then that cycle is Hamiltonian and Eulerian.

Comment: Thanks does that path have to be a simple circle? cant think on a way to draw it as not simple

Comment: How can a cycle be Hamiltonian? The start and end vertex is same in a cycle.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.

We have two criteria to meet:

> $1.$ Have either $2$ odd vertices or have none at all.
>
> $2.$ Travel to each vertex once and only once, and return to the starting point.

These can both be met, and an example is:

[image: eulerian hamiltonian graph]

(Source: "[Eulerian and Hamiltonian Graphs](http://www3.ul.ie/cemtl/pdf%20files/cm2/GraphEulerHamilton.pdf)", Mathematics Learning Center, p.3)

Note: I have assumed for criteria $2$ that you are referring to a Hamiltonian circuit.

Comment: Thanks yea i meant a circuit, does it have to be a simple circuit?

Comment: @kfir124 If it wasn't a simple circuit, then by definition it would visit some vertex more than once, and so it wouldn't be hamiltonian.

Comment: I think we need to be clear on what the question is asking.  The OP asked, "can a **path** be Hamiltonian and Eulerian at the same time."  Your answer addresses a different question, which is "can a **graph** be Hamiltonian and Eulerian at the same time."

Comment: The *graph* in the figure is both Hamiltonian and Eulerian, but the Eulerian path (circuit) visits some nodes more than once, and the Hamiltonian cannot visit all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To set the record clear: Yes.

A Path can be both Eularian and Hamiltonian. A Hamiltonian path is a spanning path, and an Eularian path goes through each edge exactly once. To consider a path holding both properties at the same time, think of the maximal path in $P_n$.